# Mule outbound http end point Content-Length mismatch

Tags: mule, endpoint

I am trying to do a basic GET/POST from one REST client to another.  I'm getting and mapping the data just fine, but it times out during the POST http oubound endpoint.  In using Fiddler Web Debugger, I found out that the problem lies with the Content-Length.  I get the error "Content-Length mismatch: RequestHeader indicated 403 bytes, but client sent 61 bytes."

If a manually set the Content-Length using the following syntax, it works without errors:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="outbound>
    <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
    <add-message-property key="Content-Length" value="61"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

I don't understand why the Content-Length is incorrect.  I can't hard-code it to 61, because the records I'm transferring are always going to have a different length.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Brett

Note: Here is the full flow:

```
<http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="slcomax.ameipro.com" port="80" path="maxrest/rest/mbo/worktype/115?_lid=mxintadm&amp;_lpwd=mxintadm" method="GET" name="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<data-mapper:config name="maxtondtypes" transformationGraphPath="maxtondtypes.grf" doc:name="maxtondtypes"/>
<flow name="ruby_rest_testerFlow1" doc:name="ruby_rest_testerFlow1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="getTypes" repeatInterval="600000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="HTTP"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="maxtondtypes" doc:name="DataMapper"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="ndeavor.ameipro.com" port="80" path="types" doc:name="HTTP" contentType="application/json">
        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound"> 
            <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
            <!-- <add-message-property key="Content-Length" value="61"/> -->
        </message-properties-transformer> 
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the flow? It seems something that happens before the HTTP outbound endpoint causes trouble. Also: Mule version?

Comment: David, I just added it to the original post.

Comment: Thanks. Just for the record `echo-component` is support old and shouldn't be used anymore. Prefer using `logger`.

Comment: OK, also the version I believe is 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the way the Quartz inbound endpoint deals with endpoint polling: it takes all the properties received from the endpoint interaction and places them in the **outbound** scope which totally messes what's downstream. It is a bug IMO: the properties should be placed in the inbound scope.

For the record, this is what the Quartz poller puts in the outbound scope:

```
Cache-Control=no-cache
Content-Language=en-US
Content-Length=360
Content-Type=application/json
Date=Thu, 18 Apr 2013 18:00:12 GMT
Expires=Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
MULE_ENCODING=UTF-8
Server=IBM_HTTP_Server
Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=0000TRNJZ71m3RLX-NDBwfC-quo:-1; Path=/
```

Because all these properties are in the outbound scope, the `http:outbound-endpoint` picks them up and uses them... hence the faulty content-length (not to mention all the other crazy headers it also sends for no reason).

The solution is to use an HTTP polling connector instead of Quartz, as shown below:

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" />
<http:polling-connector name="httpPollingConnector"
    pollingFrequency="600000" />

<http:endpoint name="worktypePoller" exchange-pattern="request-response"
    host="slcomax.ameipro.com" port="80"
    path="maxrest/rest/mbo/worktype/115?_lid=mxintadm&amp;_lpwd=mxintadm"
    method="GET" connector-ref="httpPollingConnector" />

<flow name="ruby_rest_testerFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint ref="worktypePoller" />
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="maxtondtypes" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="ndeavor.ameipro.com" port="80" path="types" connector-ref="httpConnector">
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
    </http:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Comment: David, I can't thank you enough... I'm sure you knew this already, but it's working like a charm.